# Why is my slideshow div not centered when I programmed it that way?

Tags: html, css, centering, autoresize

I am looking for my slideshow to be in the center of the screen at it's maximum size before it re sizes based on the users screen width. Here is my code so far:

HTML

```
<div id="slideshow">

                <div>

                    <a href="#"><img style="width: 100%;" border="none" src="slide_1.png"></a>

                </div>

                <div>

                    <a href="#"><img style="width: 100%;" border="none" src="slide_2.png"></a>

                </div>

                <div>

                    <a href="#"><img style="width: 100%;" border="none" src="slide_3.png"></a>

                </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#slideshow { 

    display: block;

    margin-left: auto;

    margin-right: auto;

    margin-top: 60px;

}

#slideshow > div { 

    position: absolute; 

}
```

In my index.html, I have specified that if the user's device is 1400px or greater, than the file will link to one style sheet, and if the user's device is 1399px or less, than it will link to another style sheet. My slide images are each 900px in width; and so if the user's window is greater than 900px, but less than or equal to 1399, the slides don't fill the whole screen. My question is, why doesn't the div show up centered when I specifically programmed it to? Here is the link to my site (http://www.codesrce.com) and if you want to see what I mean, re-size your browser to less than 1400px and greater that 900px.

Comment: Unless you give a block element a width, it takes up the whole available space – so there is nothing to “center”, your specified margins of `auto` then just result in an effective margin of 0 on each side …

Comment: Okay thanks. That makes sense. I guess I left out the display:block; attribute.